# Verify what display fields are highlighted on a form?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do I verify what display fields are highlighted on a form? These display fields can be either combo boxes or text fields. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you want to "verify" beyond the obvious? Are you using some sort of automation for testing? You need more details..

Comment: Yes, automated tests, I want to validate that some display fields are highlight in such that they are required to be giving a value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043706/automated-testing-of-css-and-html-front-end-coding is a start

Comment: You can try Siesta (http://www.bryntum.com/docs/siesta/) for automated tests of ExtJS applications (based on the question tag).